# It errors when I define variable in function

Tags: javascript

```js
function addNumbers(x,y) {
    sum = x + y;
    var sum;
    return sum;
}

addNumbers(5,9);
alert(sum);
```

It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined

When I put "var sum" before the function it works. What is the reason?

Comment: Is sum defined outside of the addNumbers function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, thanks for correction, didn't know that variables are hoisted in JS too.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - Only `var` ones. `let` and `const` are sane. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sum` is only defined **within** the function. To use the function's return value, you do that directly:

```js
function addNumbers(x,y) {
    var sum;
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}

alert(addNumbers(5,9));
```

or

```js
function addNumbers(x,y) {
    var sum;
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}

var outerSum = addNumbers(5,9);
alert(outerSum);
```

Also note that I moved the `var sum;` to the top of the function. It doesn't really matter with `var` (I wrote [a blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) about that), but it's better form. (It *does* matter with `let` and `const`, which you should probably be using instead of `var`.)

Answer (score 1):

A variable only exists inside of it's *scope* (rule of thumb: starts at the previous `{` ends at the matching `}`), which especially makes sense for functions, as the variables inside the function only exist as long as the function gets executed.

```
function addNumbers(x,y) { // sum can be used from here on
  var sum = x + y; // always declare variables where you ise them first, otherwide you get funny behaviour
  return sum; // <-
} // you cannot use sum from here on
```

Now that means that you cannot access `sum` outside of `addNumbers`. However as your function `return`s the value of `sum`, you can store that in another variable:

```
 var cool = addNumbers(1, 2);
```

Now you can use that `cool` variable and eventually log it.